# Azure IoT Hub Operations Monitoring

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have an Azure IoT hub that I connect devices to. I want to enable monitoring to monitor devices connecting and disconnecting from the hub.

I've enabled Verbose on Connections in the monitoring categories for my Iot hub:

[image]

My devices connect to my Hub and show in Device Explorer:

[image]

I then have an Azure Function set to log my data from the Operations Monitoring to an Azure SQL db:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static void Run(string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info(myEventHubMessage);

    try
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iotAzureSQLDb"].ConnectionString;

        log.Info(connectionString);
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MonitoringMessage>(myEventHubMessage);

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var sqlStatement = "insert into [dbo].[DeviceStatuses] " +
                                "(DeviceId, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionUpdateTime)" +
                                "values " +
                                "(@DeviceId, @ConnectionStatus, @ConnectionUpdateTime)";
            using (var dataCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
            {
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConnectionStatus", message.operationName);
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceId", message.deviceId);
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConnectionUpdateTime", message.time);

                connection.Open();
                dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();

                log.Info($"Device {message.deviceId} changed state: {message.operationName}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info(ex.Message);
    }
}

public class MonitoringMessage
{
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public string operationName { get; set; }
    public int? durationMs { get; set; }
    public string authType { get; set; }
    public string protocol { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? time { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public int? statusCode { get; set; }
    public int? statusType { get; set; }
    public string statusDescription { get; set; }
}
```

If I enable Device Identity Operations in Operations Monitoring, I get create events being logged. So I'm confident the inputs to the function is correct. However, nothing is ever created for Connections???

I can also send messages to my connected devices fine. I'm just seeing no events for connections / disconnections.

I've also tried creating a Stream Analytics and sampling the input for a period where I know I have connections / disconnections and nothing is being found.

Comment: Can you [use iothub-explorer tool to catch connection/disconnection events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring#view-events)?

Comment: That's what I'm using an alternative, the problem is you have to poll it every 'x' minutes to get what's connected / disconnected. Whereas if the IoT Monitoring worked properly, I would receive events when a device disconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by forcing my device to connect over MQTT in the dev environment and now I see it connecting and disconnecting.

Unfortunately I can't use MQTT in production.

Does anyone know if Connection / Disconnection events are only possible in MQTT as opposed to AMQP?

Comment: What about HTTP?

Comment: HTTP doesnt show connection status at all, if I connect a device over HTTP device explorer always shows it as disconnected.

Comment: HTTP exactly doesn't show connection/connection status at all. But AMQP and MQTT works for me...What kind of your IoT Hub pricing tier? And what location did you select when creating the hub?

Comment: Hub is Western Europe, tier is free as we are still in the development stage.

Comment: Mine is S1 tier. Based on your comment, I also tried on free tier but I can't even save Monitoring categories settings successfully. I'll report this issue to internal related team.

Answer (score 0):

If you just would like to get devices connection states, use REST instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/deviceapi#DeviceApi_GetDevices

Also, here's an online tool to monitor devices connection state.

https://iotdevtool.com/registry/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We invented a data flow to determine "device state".  We created a Stream Analytics Job, wired to the `Operations monitoring` (that's the `Endpoint` type in the IOT Input definition).  We have the Stream Analytics query  `SELECT INTO` a ServiceBus queue . We have a WebJob processing that queue and updating a persistent store (SQL Table, Azure Table, your pick) where we write down the status.  A UI (or WebAPI Controller) can then inspect that persistent store.

So far we have all the `Monitoring categories` (in the IOT Hub Portal blade) set to `Verbose` but may dial it down later.

We do get data.