# How to use WebJob to process IoT hub messages and save them to SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

Im trying to create a complete solution to present data from IoT devices on to a webpage.

The data and devices will never be in the millions so using Stream Analytics, Machine Learning, Big Data etc. is costly and unnecessary.

I've looked at docs, blogs, forums for weeks now, and im stuck with the part on how to process the messages that the IoT hub receives, i want to save them to a SQL database and then build a website that will present them to the users.

What i have so far:

**1. Device part**

Raspberry Pi 3 has Windows IoT Core installed
Messages are sent and recieved on both Hub and Device ends successfully
(verified with Device Explorer and IoT hub dashboard)

**2. Processing part**

The most similar approach is detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage) but i don't want to use NoSQL, ive tried to use the Azure Function with the External Table (experimental) but there is zero documentation for that and all my attempts failed with function error.

Now im trying to connect a WebJob to process IoT Hub messages but i cant find any relevant samples or docs. Essentially id want to convert a Console App to a WebJob which will be triggered when a message arrives to the IoT hub

**3. Webpage part**

Once i get the messages to the SQL database i will create my custom portal for managing and registering devices, issuing one-off commands to devices and for request-response data.

The telemetry will be queried from the database and presented statically or near real time (with SignalR) by device type, location, by user privilages etc. this part is preety clear to me.

Please can anyone help me out with the processing part??

Comment: If you have a console app doing what you want, you can just deploy it as Web Job, no changes needed. But Azure Functions are good for your use case. You don't have to use External Table binding if you have troubles with it, you can just use Entity Framework or ADO.NET to save data to your SQL db manually.

Comment: Yes, you could create an Event Hub-listening function and tie it to the Event Hub-compatible endpoint on the IoT Hub. And save it from there to DB.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Mikhail, ok ill try again with the function, I think I know now what you mean.

Comment: @astaykov I just described the problem and explained what I have done so far to solve it. if you know something about the problem in-hand then please paste some code combining the triggering function of a webjob with the IoT hub endpoint so there will be a on-site topic which is fine for StackOverflow.

Comment: Azure Function with Event Hub trigger will replace all of the code in your updated question with 2 lines, see "Trigger sample in C#" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs)

Comment: You can reference Azure Function code part of [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490633/azure-iot-hub-operations-monitoring). About how to set iot hub event trigger in Azure Function you can reference [this tutorial](https://www.10thmagnitude.com/tech-blog/step-step-guide-creating-functions-within-azures-iot-hub/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using Azure WebJobs and this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support) explains how to tie an EvenHub (IoT Hub) to the WebJob.